# How to match ID and href in an effective way using PHP?

Tags: php, string, preg-match-all

**Example string**

```
<a href="#fn2" class="fn-ref" id="s9781473910270.i12">
<a href="#fn3" class="fn-ref" id="s9781473910270.i13">

<a class="ref-fn-ref" href="#fn2">↩</a>
<a class="ref-fn-ref" href="#fn3">↩</a>
```

**Expected output**

```
<a href="#fn2" class="fn-ref" id="s9781473910270.i12">
<a href="#fn3" class="fn-ref" id="s9781473910270.i13">

<a class="ref-fn-ref" href="#s9781473910270.i12">↩</a>
<a class="ref-fn-ref" href="#s9781473910270.i13">↩</a>
```

To get my expected output, I have common string in both the anchors are `href=#fn` so that I can match both the anchors. If both hrefs are same in both the anchors then `class="ref-fn-ref"`anchor's ID should be replaced with `class="fn-ref"` anchor's ID.

I tried,

```
preg_match_all("/<a href=\"#fn([0-9]+)\"\\s*class=\"fn-ref\"\\s*id=\"(.*?)\">/s",$r,$match1);
//captured the first anchor's href no. and ID  

preg_match_all("/<a\\s*class=\"ref-fn-ref\"\\s*href=\"#fn([0-9]+)\"/s",$r,$match2);
//captured the second anchor's href no. 

for($i=0;$i<count($match1[0]);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<count($match2[0]);$j++){
        if($match1[1][$i]===$match2[1][$j]){
//if both href's same then replace First anchor's ID with second

    $tochange=preg_replace("/href=\".*?\"/s","href=\"#".$match1[2][$i]."\"",$match2[0][$j]);
    $r=str_replace($match2[0][$j],$tochange,$r);
        }}}

echo $r;
```

**Output**

```
<a href="#fn2" class="fn-ref" id="s9781473910270.i12">
<a href="#fn3" class="fn-ref" id="s9781473910270.i13">
<a class="ref-fn-ref" href="#s9781473910270.i12">↩</a>
<a class="ref-fn-ref" href="#s9781473910270.i13">↩</a>
```

Am getting the expected output. But still there would be an easiest way to do this,Just I need to know how can it be done in other ways? I hope it would be understood.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use a HTML/XML parser.

Comment: why dont you go for javascript or jquery???

Comment: As I'm comfortable with php, I stick to it.

Comment: Still better to learn in javascript in future. Also, id should be unique...You may get unexpected result if you use repeat id in same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have structured datas, you should use this structure, here is a basic example with useful DOM methods:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$linkNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($linkNodes as $linkNode) {
    if ($linkNode->hasAttribute('href') && $linkNode->hasAttribute('id'))
        echo $linkNode->getAttribute('href') . PHP_EOL .
             $linkNode->getAttribute('id') . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
}
```

For your particular requirements, you can use something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$linkNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

// first you collect references and target links in two arrays
$refs = []; // associative array with ref as key and id as value
$targets = []; // each item is an array with href value and the node itself

foreach ($linkNodes as $linkNode) {
    $href = $linkNode->getAttribute('href');

    if ($linkNode->getAttribute('class') === 'fn-ref')
        $refs[$href] = $linkNode->getAttribute('id');
    elseif ($linkNode->getAttribute('class') === 'ref-fn-ref')
        $targets[] = [$href, $linkNode];
}

// then you only need to loop over targets, check if the reference exists in $refs,
// and change the href attribute with the corresponding id value.
foreach ($targets as $target) {
    if (isset($refs[$target[0]]))
        $target[1]->setAttribute('href', '#' . $refs[$target[0]]);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This is fine. But how can I match two hrefs and replace ID?

Comment: @Vidhya: I added an example for your requirements.